# How to power on softlayer server using rest api

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

**I need to poweron softlayer virtual server by using API. I need the JSON request**
Poweroff,pause JSON request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Rest request:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/$virtualId/powerOn

Method: Get
```

Replace: $username, $apiKey and $virtualId with your own information.

References:

[SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::powerOn](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/powerOn)